# ForgeRock OpenAM doesn't log message if restarted under DevOps model

Tags: openam, forgerock

Currently, I have OpenAM deployed as a DevOps model using Kubernetes cluster service where I have disabled the liveliness of the pod so that I can restart OpenAM whenever I need(I can replace external libraries under extracted folder).

I can copy the jar into pods and can stop and start the tomcat but after that OpenAM stops logging message into log file.

I have verified that all the logging is enabled as before restart it was logging the log messages.

Currently every time I have to build a new image and deploy it which is very time taking.

Is anyone have faced similar problem ?

Comment: When the debug logger does not have the permission to write to the files, it logs to standard error . Do the log statements show up in Tomcat logs? You may also check which file descriptors are opened by Tomcat.

Comment: What you actually do there is misusing the concept of pods/container. Never try to change sth manually in your container. Always build a new image and exchange your running container. This might get you in trouble when for example the container crashes and recreates itself. This would be like a reset to your former image...

Comment: @BernhardThalmayr No nothing gets written in any of the file.

Comment: @jonasheinisch I know what you mean but from development perspective, I just wanted to test something very quickly.